# Why does the Z80 JP (absolute) instruction always take 10 states to execute?

Tags: assembly, z80

I've looked at a few different websites and they all agree that a `JP nnnn` instruction (where `nnnn` is a 16-bit address) always takes 10 states to execute.

According to what I've read, all of the following instructions take 10 states, even the conditional ones, and even if the jump is not taken:

- `JP nnnn`
- `JP c, nnnn`
- `JP nc, nnnn`
- `JP z, nnnn`
- `JP nz, nnnn`
- `JP po, nnnn`
- `JP pe, nnnn`
- `JP p, nnnn`
- `JP m, nnnn`

These sources also agree that this is *not* the case for `JR`,`CALL`, and `RET`: those instructions are faster when unconditional, and are also faster if the condition is false and no jump/call/return occurred. I would have expected the same to be true for `JP` but apparently not. Why is this?

EDIT: `JP` and `CALL` are not faster when unconditional. That was a mistake I made when looking at my chart. I was only looking at `RET` when I made that statement.

EDIT 2: The above edit should have said "`JR` and `CALL`."

[Source 1](https://sites.google.com/site/timeproofing/z80-instruction-set-1/timings)
[Source 2](http://map.grauw.nl/resources/z80instr.php)

Comment: JR and CALL are not faster when unconditional. Unconditional JR takes 12 t-states, just the same as JR cc with the condition being true. Unconditional CALL takes 17 t-states, just the same as CALL cc with the condition being true.

Comment: In fact, unconditional JR is slower than unconditional JP, so it is not even clear if these commands can be compared fairly.

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake. JR and CALL are not faster when unconditional. They're only faster when the condition is false.

Comment: @puppydrum64 - your recent edit says 'JP and CALL', I assume that's a typo.

Comment: @another-dave Doh! You're right! I almost made a third typo and nearly included RET among them.

Comment: *The above edit should have said* — couldn’t you have just put it there instead of stringing together ‘disregard what I said, I actually meant something else entirely’?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The JR instructions are slow when the branch is taken because they use a four-bit(!) ALU to compute the new address.  This calculation can't start until after the target address is fetched (which it always will be).  If the branch is skipped, the Z80 will skip those additional calculations.

When processing a JP instruction, the Z80 fetches the next two bytes and increments the program counter while doing so.  It might have been possible to add circuitry to suppress the memory fetch if the branch will be skipped, which would have saved one cycle for each of those bytes (each increment of a 16-bit register would require two cycles regardless).  Since the Z80 isn't performing any arithmetic with the target-address bytes, making use of them once they're fetched is no more expensive than discarding them.

The JR instruction as well as the IX+d and IY+d addressing modes could probably have been made a couple of cycles more efficient if the Z80 had included logic to allow the 16-bit increment/decrement unit to support +256 and -256 functions and logic to output the high byte only.  If that had been done, the increment/decrement unit could have used the high bit of the displacement to select +256 or -256 mode, and started computing a possible new high byte for the address while the ALU computed the low half.  If a carry or borrow occurred, the new address would be formed using the high byte from the increment/decrement unit and the low byte from the ALU.  If none occurred, the new address would be formed using the original address high byte and the ALU.  I wouldn't be surprised if there may have been plans to do such a thing, but space or time constraints prevented it from being implemented.  The design of the instruction set would make a lot more sense if some of the slow instructions were a couple of cycles faster.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. Interestingly, I found that `JP (HL)` only takes 4 cycles. Right now I'm doing the math to see at what point it's quicker to use `JP (HL)` than `JP abs` for a loop that's too long for a DJNZ.

Comment: If the target address is in HL, JP(HL) will be faster than JP because it requires nothing more than forwarding HL into the addressing unit for the following fetch rather than PC.  No arithmetic required.  Using a combination of RET NZ and JP (HL) will increase the "setup time" for a loop, but reduce the iteration time since the combined execution time for `RET NZ` that is not taken and `JP (HL)` which is always taken is only eight cycles.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 9 cycles (5 for the failed `RET NZ` and 4 for the `JP (HL)`?)

Comment: @puppydrum64: Is a failed NZ five rather than four?  I didn't have my chart handy, so I was quoting cycle counts from my imperfect memory.  Still a cycle faster than using a normal JP, at least if the loop executes enough times to make it worthwhile.  BTW, when copying a chunk of memory, using a four LDI instructions and DJNZ will be faster than using LDIR.  That latter instruction would have performed well as designed if the Z80 had an 8-bit ALU, but checking if BC is zero takes two cycles longer than would just checking B, and it wastes another five cycles subtracting two from the PC.

Comment: My chart and the sources say 5. No big deal. As for the LDIR thing, I'll keep that in mind. I've even heard of programmers filling 1 KB with nothing but LDIs and a RET at the end, and just calling (that address + ((1024-reps)/2)) rather than using LDIR. The lengths you can go to in assembly for optimization never cease to amaze me. It's like a magic show but for computers

Comment: I have no doubt that your charts are correct.  Using 1K worth of LDI seems a bit of a waste unless one has otherwise-unused ROM space to burn, since using 16 LDI and a DJNZ would yield performance that was within a cycle per byte of using an arbitrarily large number, and if one has to build the instructions in RAM one would spend at least 11 cycles storing each byte to RAM unless one can afford to disable interrupts in which case stack hacks could achieve performance better than would be achievable using LDI.

Comment: Marketing may have favored the ability to move up to 65535 bytes using a single instruction, but I think circuitry to support LDIW and LDDW instructions that would always move exactly two bytes while leaving BC undisturbed would have been cheaper than the circuity to manage the counter in BC, and the execution time of LDI/LDD and LDIW/LDDW could probably have been about 14 and 20 cycles, respectively, if they didn't need to bother with BC.  It wouldn't be possible to respond to interrupts within a 20-cycle LDIW, but at 20 cycles it wouldn't be the longest instruction.

Comment: I've sometimes thought it would be interesting to have a contest for people to design machines with architectures similar to the 6502, Z80, or CDP1802, with similar space and internal-timing constraints, but no need for binary compatibility, to see how the architectures might have compared were it not for the need to get both of them to market quickly.  All three processors do well for some kinds of operations, but end up being really clunky for some others, in ways that a few small tweaks could really improve without adding much circuitry (or in some cases, removing circuitry).

Comment: @supercat, no-no, you don't use "16 LDI and a DJNZ", you use 16 LDI and a JP PE. It is both faster and neater.

Comment: @introspec: Yeah, I forgot that LDI spends a couple cycles updating BC.